# Software to keep track of renovation

Tags: renovation, software

What I am looking for is some kind of software to store ideas (links, images, text) for an upcoming renovation. When the renovation starts, schedules could be kept to the same item to know when work commences on it, when it should be done, etc.

I have researched the internet and haven't exactly found what I am looking for. Being in a renovation at this moment, I am trying to use 3 pieces of software to manage everything;

- [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com) for storing images and ideas to incorporate in the renovation. Also used to store different types of finishing touches (colors/brands/etc.).
- [Evernote](http://evernote.com) for storing lists of required materials, lists of suppliers, tenders, important notes during the renovation.
- [Google Calendar](http://calendar.google.com) is used to keep the schedules of arriving materials, POC's (Points Of Completion), schedules contractors need to keep, etc.

My problem is that there is no way I can have a comprehensive overview on all this information. This is why I was wondering if someone could point me to some software which could help me keep this overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Trello](https://trello.com). I use it set up as a Kan-Ban board (think of loads of post-it notes in columns for "to do", "doing" and "done").

You can also add your own columns (so you could have a "suppliers" column for example).

You can add images and ideas, as with Pinterest, and assign dates to cards to in order to track them.

There are various plugins available too, so if you wanted to view the project as a Gantt chart, for example, you could do this too.

Comment: This is actually a great idea. I have used Trello in the past (before you could add images and other media) and was very pleased with the minimal UI and the options. I am going to look at their new features right now =)

Comment: I just finished a reno projects where I used Trello. It worked well, but the hardest part was getting my contractor to help keep it up-to-date.